# ListView doesn't show though ListView's getCount() works correctly

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

This problem that the listview doesn't show up seems to be very queer. First let me post my codes of functions concerned in activity:
        protected ListView mListView;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.result);       
    mListView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.wrdList);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String word = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //use the query to search your data somehow

        //Columns to be selected in database
        String sel[] = {"_id", "wort", DictDBHelper.get2LtrLang()};
        Cursor SrhRet = mSrhHelper.searchWord(word, sel);
        //Columns to be showed in ListView
        String col[] = {"wort", DictDBHelper.get2LtrLang()};
        showList(SrhRet, col);
        SrhRet.close();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {

    }
}

/*
 * Set the TextView to print how many words are found in database 
 */
protected void setCount(int count) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.wrdCount);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}

/*
 * Set the adapter to show the list
 * First parameter specifies the cursor of rows to be shown in ListView
 * Second one specifies columns
 */
protected void showList(final Cursor SrhRet, String[] from) {

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.entry, R.id.detail};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listitem, SrhRet, from, to, 
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    setCount(mListView.getCount());

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){         
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
            Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
            Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.ENTRY_CONTENT_URI,
                                            String.valueOf(id));
            wordIntent.setData(data);
            //Required by the update 
            SrhRet.close();
            mSrhHelper.updateHist(id);
            startActivity(wordIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

These are functions that handles a input in searchable. I've traced all variables involved but hardly find anything abnormal. However everytime I tried this function the TextView shows the correct numbers that ListView should contain! These functions worked perfectly before and I've another activity derived from this one invokes these functions that works well too.

I use listitem.xml as the contents in ListView's item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="17dp" />   
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

And my result.xml. I've double-checked the orientation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/wrdCount"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/wrdList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: General info, use fill_parent instead of match_parent. match_parent is no longer used nowadays and will give u errors in some APIs. Also try making Cursor SrhRet a global variable

Comment: @Shubhayu I developed under api15 so I don't think this one matters. And I tried that. It doesn't work either.

Comment: are there any errors or are you seeing just a blank list?

Comment: @Shubhayu No error no warning.. Nothing printed as well

Comment: If the cursor is closed (just after calling showList) how the adapter could handle it? Not sure that it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the this : `SrhRet.close();` in your `handleIntent(Intent intent)` method.

Please try to close the cursor in the `onDestroy()` method of the activity.

Comment: To close the cursor is intended to modify the table. This close function is invoked as long as I clicked item. I don't think this one prevents the listview from display. Or, even it does, why does my getCount() return correctly? @Deucalion

Comment: showList(SrhRet, col); and SrhRet.close();. You call the getCount() in showList(...). And after it you close the cursor.

Comment: It still doesn't work. This function is enclosed in onXXListener instead of being executed linearly. But thanks for your advice